# Stop Thread that is blocked reading from a readLine() method

Tags: java, multithreading, http, sockets, buffer

```
while (active) {
   String message = reader.readLine();
}


public void stop(){
   active = false;
}
```

How do i stop this `Thread` before `readLine()` return a `String`?

Comment: What?? Did you mean `How` instead of `Why`?

Comment: I don't understand. Is your thread stopping before reading a line? If you're not calling your stop method there are a couple of options that can stop that thread... but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

As you've likely identified, your boolean check is all well and good, but doesn't work if your thread blocks on network I/O, or is sleeping. Instead you need to [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) this thread. See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your BufferedReader has to be closed to unblock the reading thread.

```
public void stop() {
    closeQuietly(reader); // unblock
    active = false;
}

public static void closeQuietly(Closable c) {
    if(c != null)
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch(IOException ignored) { }
}
```

Comment: I didnt found this Classe IOUtils

Comment: Its part of the apache common IO.  Its simple code you can add yourself.

Comment: this method do .close from BufferReader.
When i try this, my application crash

Comment: @turim No it doesn't, it throws an exception, which you catch.

Comment: @turim Java applications don't just crash (except for very rare bugs) Usually they trigger Exceptions which you might not handle correctly, but that is not a crash.